# Better handling of number format exception in android

Tags: java, android, validation, exception

I've got the following code snippet that I'm thinking of refactoring to a more abstract application exception handler but I want to make sure I've got it as tidy as possible first

Any suggestions on how to improve this code or make it more resuable

```
int id = -1;
final StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder("Bad Input Value: ");
try {
        id = Integer.parseInt(edtId.getText().toString());
} catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
        errorMessage.append("Failed to parse id " + e.getMessage());
}

if (id < 0) {
    errorToast(errorMessage.toString());
} else {
    //go ahead an retreive values from database knowing the id has been parsed
    //correctly to a positive int.
}
```

Comment: What if user entered '-1' in text field?

Comment: it would be less than zero or am I missing something ?

Comment: in which case errorMessage.toString() would be a blank string, not particularly helpful

Comment: Your logic assumes values less than 0 are errors.  If the user entered a negative value, you'd be assuming there was a parsing error.  As to your question, that's app and design dependent.  Very hard to generalize out of context.  How do you report errors? Message? turn the box red? Lots of variables.

Comment: I've edited the string constructor to eliminate the ambiguity you highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why pre-assign id to a magic number?

```
try {
    int id=Integer.parseInt(edtId.getText().toString());
    //go on as normal
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //handle error
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, I think the go on as normal means the try block will contain a lot more code than I'd like it to, and I can't use the id outside the try block if i declare it inside it.

Comment: @Luke: ideally, you pass the `int` to another method handling you DB stuff. You can also work with `java.lang.Integer` and its 'null feature'.