# My android app crashes when I use it, and Android studio shows "FATAL EXCEPTION"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have been working on a tip calculator android app recently, and today I have been trying to add a way to divide a bill. However, my app is crashing upon use because of it. I have been trying to figure out what is making it crash, but I can't seem to find anything. Whenever I use my app now, I get this error:

```
    Process: com.gradient.tiptime, PID: 6507
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{2d3edb1 VFED..CL. .F...... 600,60-1080,196 #7f0700d1 app:id/split_num aid=1073741825}"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at com.gradient.tiptime.MainActivity.calculateTip(MainActivity.kt:26)
        at com.gradient.tiptime.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:19)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7192)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7166)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:824)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27592)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

And this is the function that my "calculate" button calls:

```kotlin
fun calculateTip() {
        var mealCost: Double = cost_of_service.text.toString().toDouble()
        var splitNum: Double = split_num.toString().toDouble()

        val selectedId = tip_options.checkedRadioButtonId
        val tipPercentage = when(selectedId) {
            R.id.option_twenty_percent -> 0.20
            R.id.option_eighteen_percent -> 0.18
            else -> 0.15}

        //some values
        var tip = tipPercentage * mealCost
        val addedCost = tip + mealCost

        //finds the views
        val switch: Switch = findViewById(R.id.round_up_switch)
        val result: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tip_result)
        val total: TextView = findViewById(R.id.total_cost)
        val splitResult: TextView = findViewById(R.id.split_cost)
        val roundUp = switch.isChecked

        var split: Double = mealCost / splitNum
        var splitString: String = split.toString()

        //if roundup switch is checked, rounds tip up
        if (roundUp) {
            tip = kotlin.math.ceil(tip)}

        //formats the tip to $
        val formattedTip = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tip)
        val formattedCost = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(addedCost)

        //changes the textViews in the app
        result.text = getString(R.string.tip_amount, formattedTip)
        total.text = getString(R.string.total_amount, formattedCost)
        splitResult.text = getString(R.string.total_amount, splitString)
    }
```

Comment: `split_num.toString().toDouble()` should probably be `split_num.text.toString().toDouble()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better handling of number format exception in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125163/better-handling-of-number-format-exception-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code and the error you have provided the error looks in the line

```
var splitNum: Double = split_num.toString().toDouble()
```

Change this line to

```
var splitNum: Double = split_num.text.toString().toDouble()
```

The error here seems that the compiler is having trouble converting the EditText field into Double type which is not possible and results in casting error.